# exec -t is invalid

Tags: linux, terminal, x11, software-installation, exec

I made an rpm that installs a `.run` file and whenever I run the rpm and the rpm tries to execute the .run file I keep getting the error that `exec -t is an invalid option` at the following lines of code

```
if test `echo "$0" | cut -c1` = "/"; then # Spawn a terminal!
                    exec $XTERM -title "$label" -e "$0" --xwin "$initargs"
                else
                    exec $XTERM -title "$label" -e "./$0" --xwin "$initargs"
```

However, if I run the `.run` on its own it installs fine. Why might this be happening? Also, what does the if statement do in this code?

Comment: What shell are you using? None of these options are available on my bash's builtin exec. Anyway, in most programs long options need two dashes, not one. Does it work if you use `--title "$label"`?

Comment: if I run the .run file from the command line it works, with `exec $XTERM -title "$label" -e "$0" --xwin "$initargs`. However when the rpm runs the file it doesn't work which is weird.

Comment: I understand that. Which is why I asked you two questions. So, what shell are you using and what happens if you try it with `--title` instead?

Comment: I am using bash and I cant edit it once it is in the rpm since the rpm sucks the file in but ill try it from the command line

Comment: `--` is invalid it says

Comment: I'm very surprised it works then, none of these options are available for my `exec`. Anyway, it is likely that the rpm file is not using bash  but whatever `/bin/sh` is on your system instead. Please also mention your distribution.

Comment: I did `/bin/sh --version` and I got bash.

Comment: It seems like `XTERM` is not present in the environment that rpm runs commands in, so it winds up running `exec -title ...`.

Comment: yes I think that is the issue. I will go further back to figure out what `XTERM` is getting set to.

Comment: When I run it in runlevel 3 it works though for the rpm

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I think the system I am using doesnt like consoles from x-11. Since other run levels work fine.

Comment: Suggestion: wrap those script lines inside an `if [ -n "$XTERM" ]; then ... else echo "error: XTERM variable is not set" >&2 ; fi` statement.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I didnt something like that where if it cant find the xterm command it doesnt try to use xterm and just uses bash.

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion #1

I don't think you can run an XTERM like this since the RPM when being installed is run under a different userid (root) than the use that owns the desktop.

For this to work, at a minimum, you'd need to perform a `xhost +` on your primary desktop as your userid, and then be sure to set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable in that call to XTERM. Something like this might work:

```
exec DISPLAY=:0.0 $XTERM .....
```

I think XTERM can also take the `-display` switch to do something similar as well, but I don't have it handy at the moment.

#### Suggestion #2

If you're encountering a "exec -t is an invalid option" then I would suspect that the variable, `$XTERM`, is going unset thus resulting in the command `exec -title ...` being executed, and failing.

*Example*

```
$ exec -title "blah" -e "bash"
bash: exec: -t: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

However when I set `$XTERM` and retry, it works:

```
$ XTERM=xterm
$ exec $XTERM -title "blah" -e "bash"
```

[image: ss#1]

Comment: I actually do get that window on one of my vms, I also have one that needs to comply with DISA STIGS that I think those may be causing the issue. Since it also works on runlevel 3 but not a GUI runlevel.